# Wordpress plugin to return PHP for pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been having an issue getting one PHP statement to work with WordPress.
Basically, what I want is this:

- Return an output based on user selection

Now I have managed to get most of my stuff working, but when I try to return PHP code from my plugin to wordpress it gets commented out straightaway.
  This is my code for the function I'm using.

```
function display($type, $status) {
$html ='';
if($type == null) {
    $html = "<?php echo do_shortcode[contact-form-7 id='7' title='Campaign monitor']');?>";
}else if($type == "ios") {
    if ($status == "y") 
    $html = "IOS";
}else if($type == "android") {
    if ($status == "y") 
    $html = "ANDROID";
}
echo $html;

}
```

So as you can see depending on what is picked e.g.

```
 <?php echo display(ios, y); ?>
```

It displays the IOS on my website, however things get interesting when the type is null e.g.

```
 <?php echo display(); ?>
```

This returns the following

```
<!--?php echo do_shortcode[contact-form-7 id='7' title='Campaign monitor']');?-->
```

Straightaway my PHP is commented out and I can't do anything to get it working.
Although, I do understand it's not the best practise to do it this way (by returning raw php) I have no other way to do it.

Is there anyway to overcome this issue?
I have tried EXEC-PHP plugin as well as PHP Code for Posts and Pages plugins.

Comment: This is not possible. You cant return PHP code like that. PHP code is server-side. What you're doing is creating a string.

Comment: In what file is  `function display` located?

Comment: function display is located in my custom template php file.

Comment: would that be your theme's `index.php` or `functions.php` ?

Comment: It's a custom template for my homepage so neither of those. So e.g. template_homepage.php

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish here?  You're being very specific in the question, but we need a bigger context to provide an answer. For example, are you trying to target shortcodes in a post based on user-agent?

Comment: Yes exactly something like this, I want to display contact form for specific devices and download button for mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really sure what the effect you want is but you were saving a string into html from your do_shortcode. I assume you are confusing php resolving variables inside double quotes with functions being resolved. Not so. This should be what you are looking for.

```
function display($type, $status) {
    $html ='';
    if($type == null) {
        $html = do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="7" title="Campaign monitor" ]');
    }else if($type == "ios") {
        if ($status == "y") 
        $html = "IOS";
    }else if($type == "android") {
        if ($status == "y") 
        $html = "ANDROID";
    }
    echo $html;

}
```

Comment: Works as I hoped it would. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as it helps cut down on code, and helps the function be a bit more clear. It assumes that if the device type is not listed above, that you want to display the default case. It assumes that if your device is not listed, in this case, anything other than android and ios, that it should display the default case, which is your CF7 shortcode. IF you want to specify other options, they need to be done ABOVE 'default'. As stated in comments elsewhere, this is PHP, so it's server-side processing..

```
<?php 
function display($type, $status){
    switch ($type){
        case "ios":
            $html = "IOS";
            break;
        case "android":
            $html = "Android";
            break;
        default:
            $html = "do_shortcode[contact-form-7 id='7' title='Campaign monitor']";
            break; 
    }
    if($status == "active"){
        echo $html;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It does exactly the same thing as my code, the key point is to get shortcode to work. But it either shows commented out code or just like here, plain string.

Comment: It does the same thing, yes, except that it doesn't include the opening and closing tags for <?php and ?> within the variable, which is being echo by PHP already, which was open to begin with. What "should" be compiled for you by the server is: echo do_shortcode[contact-form-7 id='7' title='Campaign monitor'];

If that's not what's being produced, I would look in other areas too, to see why perfectly good code is being altered. 

Exactly how are you calling this? Is the function in functions.php, and then being called in template_homepage.php?

Comment: Function is located in my plugin file and then display() is called in my template file.